# How do I make a action over ride multiple other actions if they are being called?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, events, tween, event-listener

I am working on an interactive map.

When each country is tapped a information box tweens into view and then after a delay of 5 seconds tweens out again. This all works fine.

```
//Algeria

    algeria_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showAlgeria)
    function showAlgeria (e:MouseEvent)
    {

            TweenLite.to(algeria_txt, 1, {autoAlpha:1});
            OverwriteManager.init(2);
            TweenLite.to(algeria_txt, 1, {autoAlpha:0, delay:5});   

    }




//Bahrain
    bahrain_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showBahrain)
    function showBahrain (e:MouseEvent)
    {

        TweenLite.to(bahrain_txt, 1, {autoAlpha:1});
        OverwriteManager.init(2);
        TweenLite.to(bahrain_txt, 1, {autoAlpha:0, delay:5});

    }
```

But if someone select another country before the end of the delay i get an over lapping of text boxes.

I want a short way of saying if any other country text box is visible, make this invisible first then make the one selected visible. I don't want to have to refer to each country as there is over twenty of them.

Is there a short way to do this? I have put all the countrys in an array

```
var countrys_txt:Array =[algeria_txt, bahrain_txt, cote_txt, dubai_txt, dubai_txt, ghana_txt, iran_txt, jordan_txt, kenya_txt, kuwait_txt, libya_txt, oman_txt, safrica_txt, palestine_txt, mauritius_txt, qatar_txt, saudi_txt, sudan_txt, syria_txt, tunisia_txt, turkey_txt, yemen_txt, nigeria_txt];
```

and thought maybe i could call on this?

Whats the best quick solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this.

You create a var to store the current info box, whenever a new info box is shown, you hide the current one.

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    //create a global var to hold a reference to the current info box
    var curInfoBox:MovieClip;

    //create a timer to make the current info box go away after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)
    var goawayTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);

    //run the goawayTimerTick function whenever the timer ticks
    goawayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goawayTimerTick);

    function goawayTimerTick(e:TimerEvent) {
        if (curInfoBox) {
            hideInfoBox(curInfoBox);
        }
    }

    //create function to show an info box to reduce redundant code
    function showInfoBox(box:MovieClip) {
        TweenLite.to(box, 1, { autoAlpha:1 } );
        OverwriteManager.init(2);

        //if there's something in the curINfoBox var, hide it
        if (curInfoBox) {
            hideInfoBox(curInfoBox);
        }

        curInfoBox = box;

        //reset and start the timer to that makes it go away after 5 seconds
        goawayTimer.reset();
        goawayTimer.start();
    }

    function hideInfoBox(box:MovieClip) {
        TweenLite.to(box, 1, { autoAlpha: 0 } );
    }

    //now setup all your buttons
    algeria_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showAlgeria)
    function showAlgeria (e:MouseEvent)
    {
        showInfoBox(algeria_txt);
    }
```

---

You could minimize redundancy further, by doing something along these lines:

```
//create an array of all your country buttons
var mapButtons:Array = [algeria_mc, bahrain_mc, cote_mc, dubai_mc]; //etc with all of them

//iterate over that array and attach a click listener to each item
for(var i:int=0;i<mapButtons.legnth;i+){
    mapButtons[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mapButtonClick);
}


function mapButtonClick(e:MouseEvent){
    //the passed event (e) has a property called currentTarget
    //that is a reference to object you attached the listener to, eg the item clicked

    //we take the instance name of the item clicked, and replace the _mc with _txt to get a reference to it's info box
    var infoBox:MovieClip = getChildByName(e.currentTarget.name.replace("_mc","_txt")) as MovieClip;

    //now show the box
    showInfoBox(infoBox);
}
```

Comment: Thank you the top Answer works perfect and has taught we a few things i can apply else where - Cheers!